# How to select equivalent replacement ignitor for metal halide fixture?

Tags: light-fixture, ballast

Situation:

- I inherited 3 100W overhead fishing lights (metal halide with pulse start) and one of them died
- circuit doesn't have a capacitor, but has ignitor; bulb is marked with `M90/E`; fixture uses 120V AC, but multimeter shows 240V at the bulb base
- by moving parts (ballast, bulb and ignitor) to other fixtures I figured that ignitor is not working
- ignitor is marked with `CAT NO IG-240` and `CL-010805`. I found it's pic [here](https://www.lighting-gallery.net/gallery/displayimage.php?album=4087&pos=0&pid=149382).

I can't find this ignitor anywhere online. Looks like it is discontinued. Is it possible to replace it with an equivalent? How to select one? (until few days ago I never heard about MH bulbs)

Should I discard/bypass all this and install some LED bulb instead?

Comment: Keep in mind "shop for me" questions are off-topic on SE.  I'd sell the whole shebang on Craigslist (HID lights are highly sought-after by those doing indoor horticulture).  Then get LEDs to suit you.  Least, I gather you aren't doing fishing *at your house*, so LED means less battery to haul around. And many LED solutions are available at 12V and 24V.   LED isn't wildly more efficient than metal halide (2x at most) but that's still half the battery.

Comment: There are a number of different kinds of ignitors for MH. Not just one kind. So there is no bright line answer. If I were crazy enough to want to make this work, I'd tear the case apart and see what's inside of it. You already know it is bad, so there is no harm in seeing what is in there. That will tell a lot about what it does and how and therefore how you might either figure a replacement or else fix what you see there. (It's possible you can fix it, though I doubt it right now. I have fixed things like this before. So maybe.) Anyway, need to see what's inside I think.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine Well, I am not asking for shopping help. I don't know how to select ignitor that will work in this circuit. My knowledge about HID is very limited, but apparently there are many different circuit types and ignitor from one is unlikely to work in another. Btw, these lights are stationary -- attached to the poles on the dock. :)

Comment: @jonk I was hoping there are only few different types of ignitors and replacement can be selected by simply looking at data printed on my ignitor :-(

Comment: @jonk IS there any way to check if [this ignitor](https://lightbulbsurplus.com/keystone-ignitor-xg-04/) will work in my case?